# Need to install sun-java5-jdk on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, java, ubuntu-11.04

I've found debian package on http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/devel/sun-java5-jdk
It depends on sun-java5-jre. So I'm going to http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/sun-java5-jre to install it first. But it depends on sun-java5-jdk!! How is it possible to install???

Answer (score 1):

Hi just download all 4 hardy packages (from the same location you have posted [i can't post more than 2 urls, sorry]) into one directory.

- sun-java5-bin_1.5.0-15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- sun-java5-demo_1.5.0-15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- sun-java5-jdk_1.5.0-15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- sun-java5-jre_1.5.0-15-0ubuntu1_all.deb

And then run the command

```
sudo dpkg -i sun-java5*.deb
```

And after this has finished (i think it will complain about unixodbc and some things) run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then you should have a running java 1.5.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to install java5 (in order to compile froyo on a 32 bits system) on ubuntu 11.04 and this did the trick in my case:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy multiverse"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java5-jdk
```

It took a while, some unrelated warnings were fired, but at the end it was installed. After the installation was finished I just did:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and switched to java5, which was one of the alternatives.

You should be able to go back to java 6 after that just by issuing an uptade-alternatives call.